# Prove you can place binary words in a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A binary word of length $n$ is the series of $n$ elements that each one of them is $0$ or $1$.
Let $A$ be the set of all the binary words of length $n$.

Prove you can place all the elements of $A$ in a circle such that two consecutive words have a difference of only ONE $1$ or ONE $0$

For example, $n=3$ :
    [image]

I tried thinking of a recursive-like algorithm to do so but it did not work. I thought by starting at $000$ then $001$ however we cannot put $010$ because it is different from the previous by 2 digits number (0 changed to 1 and 1 changes to 0 from 001 -> 010)  so we move to $011$ and so on...
This is not a proof and it does not work either (the algorithm)

I even tried to start proving by induction, but it sounds ridiculous because I can't think of how to prove that you can "draw a circle using n=k+1" using the assumption that you can draw it using words of length $n=k$

Edit something interesting I found:
if you draw $n=2$ then you get:

[image]

Then add $0$ to the left of each word, you get:

[image]

You get the beginning of the first image.. but I am not sure how to make it rigorous...

I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: You want a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Prove the statement by induction.

Here is the inductive step $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$.

You know that you can place all the binary workds of length $n$ in a circle $x_1-x_2-x_3-...-x_{2^n}-x_1$.

Now, show that the following works
$$x_10-x_20-...-x_{2^n}0-x_{2^n}1-x_{2^n-1}1-...x_11-x_10$$
where $x_k0$ and $x_k1$ are the binary words made by $x_k$ followed by 0 or 1.

In other words: add a zero at the end of each word, go around the circle without closing it, and come back around the circle, this time adding a 1 at the end.

Comment: If I add a 0 at the beginning - would it work the same way? Thank you!

Comment: @Remember1312 If you mean a 0 at the begging and a 1 at the beginning for the return trip, the answer is yes. Actually, you can fix any possition inside the "n+1" bit, and insert the 0 or 1 at that particular possition.

Comment: But one thing that I did not quite understand, is how $X_{2^n}$ takes both $0$ and $01$ (at the middle of the line) and are you talking about- half the circle being filled with 0 and the other half with 1's ?

Comment: @Remember1312 Just look at an example. Lets say that you have the following circle for $2$-bits: $00-01-11-10-00$. Here is the new circle for 3 bits $$000-010-110-100-101-111-011-001-000$$ If you draw the suggested cicles on a circle it will become much more clear

Comment: @Remember1312 You add a 0 at the end of the bits in the cycle, and then a 1 at the end of the return cicle.

Comment: I still don't get it, what is the return circle? I tried  drawing it but after I added 0 to each of the values there I was stuck

Comment: @Remember1312 $X_1,..., X_{2^n}$ are the $n$ bit words, in the order they appear in the circle. Now we create a circle with all the $n+1$ bits. Note that each $n+1$ bit word is exactly one of the $X_k$ with 0 or 1 in front (since you preffer it)

Comment: So, your circle is $0X_1-0X_2-...-0X_{2^n}$ (this way we cover all words starting with 0). Then, you go from $0X_{2^n}$ to $1X_{2^n}$ and start going backwards $1X_{2^n}-1X_{2^n-1}-...-1X_1$. Now close the circle $1X_1-0X_1$

Comment: Still, I don't get why for example my circle is $00-01-11-10$ then you said we put 0 so: $000-001-011-010$ and then put $1$ so $1000-1001-1011-1010$ , this is now not a complete circle with 4 bits.

Comment: @Remember1312 NO. You put the one at the beginning of the ORIGINAL circle, not the new circle, in reverse order. Or alternately, in your approach, REPLACE the first digit by a 1 for the return.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the fact that the hypercube graph $Q_n$ with $2^n$ vertices has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: I did not study hamiltonian cycles yet

Comment: @Remember1312 A Hamiltonian cycle is a cycle in a graph where we visit each vertex exactly once. The hypercube graph $Q_n$ can be constructed as follows: vertices are $n$-bit binary strings and we connected two vertices with an edge if and only if the corresponding binary strings differ by a single digit. It is well known that $Q_n$ is Hamiltonian. Hopefully this solution is interesting to you even if it does not prove the claim from first principles.